# cannot import name 're_path' I am using django version 2.0.6

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to use re_path from django.urls, django doc says I can use this from django version 2,

From the error I came to know that I am using django version 2.0.6.

But I am not able to re_path

> ImportError at /
>
> cannot import name 're_path'
>
> Request Method:   GET Request URL:    http://djangosite.com/ Django Version:
>     2.0.6 Exception Type:   ImportError Exception Value:
>
> cannot import name 're_path'
>
> Exception Location:   /home/sugushiva/myproject/filope/blogs/urls.py in
>   , line 1 Python Executable:   /usr/bin/python3

In main urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path,include

urlpatterns= [
    path('admin/',admin.site.urls),
    re_path('^$', include('blogs.urls'))
]
```

in blogs.urls

```
from django.db import re_path
from .models import blogindex

urlpatterns = [
    re_path('^$',blogindex)
]
```

Comment: We're not going to be able to help you much unless you show us your actual code where you are trying to import this module...

Comment: @solarissmoke as ssh and google compute engine I am not able to copy and and paste the code. but I will type the code here

Comment: @solarissmoke sir I updated question, please tell me sir if you want more details

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are importing the wrong path in `blogs/urls.py`.

```
from django.db import re_path
```

Should instead be:

```
from django.urls import re_path
```